# How do I fix a raised repair on plaster after it’s been painted?

Tags: painting

I fixed a spot in the plaster and when I painted it you could see the raised edges. How do I fix that now that it’s been painted?

Answer (score 1):

Just done that job this morning! Use sandpaper, with a block of wood bigger that the blemish, and, depending on the height of the plaster bump, start with maybe 180 grit, which will leave score marks. Keep the woodblock to reduce the gauge  of sandpaper, knocking it regularly to dislodge stray plaster dust, until you're down to maybe 320 grit, and the scar has disappeared.

Comment: Doesn't the success of this approach depend on what material was used for the patch?  Something like Durabond is very hard or impossible to sand once it sets up.

Comment: @SteveSh - quite probably. Which renders the question invalid until OP tells us some vital information.

Answer (score 0):

Sand it all lightly with 240 grit, sand the high spots flat, add plaster to the low spots.

Sand flat with 240 grit or finer.,
inspect the flatness using with light from a low angle.
repeat as necessary.

Seal, and repaint.

Comment: Use a long straightedge sanding block to sand with, and you might need to start a bit coarser  if it's raised up much.